# How to achieve 'Orange and Teal' look in GIMP

Tags: gimp, linux, color-grading

I would like to give the 'Orange & Teal' look to some pictures using only GIMP. I must remark, the question is specifically restricted to GIMP.

My question is simple but here is some background. 'Orange and Teal', also called 'The Blockbuster Look' is the practice of color grading pictures and movies in a simplified palette where shadows are turned into blue and lights are given an orange tone. Hated by many, it is being abused in Hollywood productions more and more, but as any other technique it also can be used very creatively to achieve kind of a warm sunset look.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the Curves tool you can use curves to achieve this effect.

To make a color adjustment with curves, there are three channels that you can work with: Red, Green or Blue. To get the other colours in the spectrum, you have to mix these by either adding or subtracting various amounts of red, green or blue.

Luminance Curves Adjustment for Teal & Orange Look:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Red Curves Adjustment for Teal & Orange Look:

[image: ![enter image description here][2]][2]

Green Curves Adjustment for Teal & Orange Look:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Blue Curves Adjustment for Teal & Orange Look:

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

What you are doing is adding "Teal" to the shadows by subtracting red (to get cyan) and adding blue to the darker tonal range of the image. To get "Orange" into the highlights you subtract blue (to get yellow) from the highlights and add some red. If you get a slight magenta cast in the highlights you can add some green to compensate.

Comment: @usr2564301Charts, graphs, and tables are not subject to copyright protection because they do not meet the first
requirement for copyright protection. It's doubtful that they can have a claim on a output chart like that.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor I am applying your curves to the left side of this picture but I don't get anything similar to the right side. Am I missing something? https://i.ytimg.com/vi/b2nPaGYkQSs/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: @Mephisto That example is from a whole other program, Adobe Premiere, and it is on a video not a still image.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor Of course, but it shows what I would like to achieve. It is an example of Orange and Teal look, no matter how it was done.

Comment: @usr2564301 - it's not GIMP's curves dialog. [Here's GIMP's](https://imgur.com/a/Uah3x) - but it doesn't matter. Essentially they work the same.

Comment: Here's an official Gimp tutorial with downloadable orange & teal curves (below just before the conclusions): https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Color_Curves/

Comment: @Ovaryraptor can you edit your answer and add that these screenshots are from a different application, but that they work exactly the same in any application which offers similar adjustments?

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher Done

Answer (score 4):

Here's another method. This one uses a Hue-Saturation adjustment in GIMP

Find a similar image of a beach scene.

- Click *Colors > Hue-Saturation*
- Hit the Red option, and max out the Overlap slider
- Make adjustments to the hue and saturation for the reds
- Choose the Blue option, and make hue and saturation adjustments
  for the blues.

Example
[image]

You can also save the adjustment as a preset. Just hit the Plus icon next to the presets.  Obviously the settings might have a different result depending on the starting image, you may need to tweak them to your requirements.

Comment: Wow this is awesome and easy to implement (+1). Thanks! I have to accept only one answer nevertheless, and the other one is technically slightly better because it gives precise control over shadows/lights.